# Asp.Net MVC 4 Wildcard Route Mapper Challenge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to use wildcards in a route config?

I want to make
    `http://localhost/documents-about-cats?animal_id=4&type_id=2`
Route to:
    `http://localhost/home/search?animal_id=4&type_id=2`

And
    `http://localhost/browse-documents-about-cats?animal_id=4&page=1`
Route to:
    `http://localhost/browse/index?animal_id=4&page=1`

But!
    `http://localhost/`
Must route to:
    `http://localhost/home/index`

Im hoped that the MVC 4 route mapper could handle wildcards so I can do something like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Search",            // Route name
            "documents-about-*", // URL with parameters
            new {
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Search"
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Browse",                   // Route name
            "browse-documents-about-*", // URL with parameters
            new {
                controller = "Browse", 
                action = "Index"
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",            // Route name
            "",                   // URL with parameters
            new {
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index"
            }
        );
```

But these route mappings don't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across a post that tackles the problem above as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Search",            // Route name
            "documents-about-{any}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Search",
                any = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Browse",                   // Route name
            "browse-documents-about-{any}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Browse",
                action = "Index"
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Blank",            // Route name
            "",                   // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                any = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

It seems to work for all scenarios required - can anyone confirm that this is the correct way to do this?